# Find $\int^r_{-r} \sqrt{r^2 - x^2} \:dx$ where r is a positive constant. #2

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Find $\int^r_{-r} \sqrt{r^2 - x^2} \:dx$ where r is a positive constant.

This question is related to but different from [Find $\int^r_{-r} \sqrt{r^2 - x^2} \:dx$ where r is a positive constant.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2173380/find-intr-r-sqrtr2-x2-dx-where-r-is-a-positive-constant/2173391#2173391).

---

**Textbook Solution**

$\int^r_{-r} \sqrt{r^2 - x^2} \:dx$

Using $x = r\sin(\theta)$ it follows that $dx = r\cos(\theta) \:d\theta$. In addition we need to take into account that $x = \pm r$ results in $\theta = \pm \pi/2$. Therefore we get:

$\int^r_{-r} \sqrt{r^2 - x^2} \:dx = \int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2} r\cos(\theta)r\cos(\theta)\:d\theta$.

---

How did the textbook get from $\int^r_{-r} \sqrt{r^2 - x^2} \:dx$ to $\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2} r\cos(\theta)r\cos(\theta)\:d\theta$? [I understand how to get the change in the limits of integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2173380/find-intr-r-sqrtr2-x2-dx-where-r-is-a-positive-constant/2173391#2173391), but I cannot find any way to reproduce $r\cos(\theta)r\cos(\theta)$ from $\sqrt{r^2 - x^2}$.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: When you trig sub you're going to get $r^2-(rsin\theta)^2$ under the radical which by Pythagorean theorem gets $r^2cos^2\theta$ under the radical.

Comment: @Heavenly96 thanks for the response. Can you please show me how the pythagorean theorem allows us to do this?

Comment: The theorem states $cos^2\theta + sin^2\theta = 1$ so that means $1-sin^2\theta = cos^2\theta$. Now, the way I explain this to people is imagine that the $1 = a$ where a is a constant, then we end up with $a^2-a^2sin^2\theta = a^2cos^2\theta$ now in your case, you have r instead of a. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Heavenly96 Yes, I understand now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there anything else about the solution that is confusing or was that where the confusion was? I assumed so, but correct me if I'm wrong and I can explain further.

Comment: @Heavenly96 That was where my confusion was. You've answered it perfectly. :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is the equation of the upper half of a circle centred at the origin. The result should be $\frac{\pi r^2}{2}$, or half the area of a circle with radius $r$.

Comment: clever.....(+1)

Answer (score 0):

[Integration by substitution for single variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_single_variable) works like this

> Let $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an interval and $\phi:[a,b]\to I$ be a differentiable function with integrable derivative. Suppose that $f : I \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function. Then
>   $$\int_{\phi(a)}^{\phi(b)}f(x)~dx = \int_a^b f(\phi(t))\phi'(t)~dt$$

In the integral you give, setting $\phi(t)=r\sin t$ and $f(x) = \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}$ can simplify the integral for you to solve it. So, the limits of your integral will change accordingly i.e.
$$-r = \phi(a) = r\sin a \\ r = \phi(b) = r\sin b$$
So, $a = -\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and $b = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$. Also, 
$$f(\phi(t))\phi'(t) = r\cos t \cdot r\cos t \tag{Using Pythagoras' theorem}$$
Now, your integral simplifies to
$$\int^r_{-r} \sqrt{r^2 - x^2} ~dx = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} r\cos t \cdot r\cos t ~dt$$
Although you will rarely see people use substitution like this, it is worth knowing what is going on behind the scenes.